# save datepicker value in mysql database

Tags: php, jquery

i`m trying to insert data value to database using jquery datapicker. my html code as follow

```
<form name="post-job" method="post" action="post-job.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading"><h3>Job Details</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<table class="table">
<tr>
<td>Date</td>
<td> <input type="text" id="edate"  value="<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"]) && ($suc == 0)) {
echo $edate;
}
?>" required name="edate" class="form-control col-lg-12 "  placeholder="Job Title"></td>
</tr>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post Job">

<table>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

my php code as follow

```
 <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $edate=$_POST['edate'];
 $q=mysql_query(insert into job(date) values('$edate')) or die(mysql_error());
 }
 ?>
```

script for date picker

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#edate').datepicker({minDate: 0});
});
</script>
```

when i run this code date is saving as 0000-00-00
so how do i solve this issue?

Comment: Where is your edate element? I didnt see an input with id of edate

Comment: i update my code.please have a look now

Comment: Make sure your input has an id of enddate

Comment: the jquery **#** selector finds by id

Comment: default `datepicker` is `m/d/Y`, but it looks like your `date` column is `Y-m-d`. Are you formatting your value to match your column format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
$edate=strtotime($_POST['edate']); 
$edate=date("Y-m-d",$edate);
$q=mysql_query(insert into job(`date`) values('$edate')) or die(mysql_error());
```

and also use backtick for column name date.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#edate').datepicker({
minDate: 0,
dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
});
});
</script>
```